# F-Statistics instead Chi Square for ANOVA results

Tags: r, statistics

can anyone tell me how to get other output statistics for my ANOVA results? I want a result table with the sum of squares (SS), the number of degrees of freedom (df), the F-statistic and the corresponding p-value.

But so far I only get Chisq, Df, Pr(>Chisq) output.

Thanks in advance for the help.

```
# Fit the classical model
model1 <- lmer(avgAmplitude ~ stimulusAge * stimulusResponse * congruency * subjectType + (1|id), data = dataset1)
library (car)
Anova(model1)
```

[Here an excerpt of the data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/554qI.png)

- played around with several packages: ezanova, afex
- changed type-argument in car::Anova()

Comment: Your picture is useless, use `dput` to share your data, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Please don't upload code, error messages, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) - and [these](https://xkcd.com/2116/).

Answer (score 1):

Set the `test.statistic=` argument to `"F"`

```
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject), sleepstudy)
car::Anova(fm1, test.statistic="F")
# Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II Wald F tests with Kenward-Roger df)
# 
# Response: Reaction
#          F Df Df.res    Pr(>F)    
# Days 169.4  1    161 < 2.2e-16 ***
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

By the way, this is also in the documentation `?car::Anova` ;)